# Excel VBA 2010 issue with selecting and moving table after pasting into Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have the code below which I found online to copy paste a tble from excel to powerpoint. After pasting the table into the slide, it fails on `PPSlide.Shapes(1).Select` with a Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shape.Select : Invalide request. To select a shape, its view must be active.
I've been searching and trying different things but can't seem to figure it out.. I thought after the paste that the table would be active and the code would jsut continue but it doesn't unless I activate/select the table in the slide and then click Run. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Dim pp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object
Dim Rng As Range

DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Data_Display.pptx"
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
pp.Visible = True
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("CA1:CJ" & Count + 1)

Rng.Copy

SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount, 12)
pp.ActivePresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

PPSlide.Shapes(1).Select
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, True
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 65
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 7.2
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700

Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set pp = Nothing
```

Comment: In what format you want to copt the Excel's Range to the PowerPoint Slide ? A Picture ? as what ?

Comment: As a table, keeping basically the same source formatting. That doesn't seem to be the issue, its the lines of code afterwards to move the table in the slide that fails.

Comment: Have you tried adding PPSlide.Select right before your PPSlide.Shapes(1).Select ?

Comment: Hi Rich, I think that was the missing link. Your suggestion also worked - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppPres = pp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
pp.Visible = True

' first set the Slide and select it
SlideCount = ppPres.Slides.Count
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount, 12)
ppSlide.Select

' have the Copy part right beofre youe Paste it to PowerPoint
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("CA1:CJ" & Count + 1)
Rng.Copy

pp.ActivePresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

Dim myShape As Object
' set up the Pasted shape to an object
Set myShape = ppSlide.Shapes(ppSlide.Shapes.Count)

With myShape
    ' set-up the shape properties

End With
```